# Проблема с npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

При попитке установить модули `npm install` не устанавливает их и выдает ошибку

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=400  
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself  
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.   
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.   
npm ERR! network  
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the    
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'        
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:    
npm ERR!     D:\work\projects\Ether\npm-debug.log
```

пересмотрел много похожых ошибок но не помогает ни `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` ни остальное

Comment: у меня как-то касперский такую ошибку вызывал

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму у меня антивируса нет

Comment: От имени администратора запускал?

Comment: С другой стороны пишет про отсутствие сети. Может сеть за каким нить корпоративным фаерволом?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov с правами администратора запускал, с домашней сети тоже не работает, хотя у коллеги все нормально

Comment: может это? http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=48681

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to get it to install to your home directory instead.

`sudo npm config set prefix ~/npm`

Fix your paths
Next, you need to add the appropriate paths to your environment variables…

*# open your .bashrc (Linux) or .bash_profile (Mac) file for editing:*

```
nano ~/.bashrc # for Linux
```

## or...

nano ~/.bash_profile # for Mac if you haven't created a .bashrc file

*# add these lines:*

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/npm/bin"

export NODE_PATH="$NODE_PATH:$HOME/npm/lib/node_modules"
```

*# save the file and then enter this command to make the changes take effect:*

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

*# or...*

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

**Take ownership
Now you need to take ownership of everything that has previously been* `installed in ~/.npm.`
Anything that was previously installed using sudo npm install will be owned by root and will cause problems later.*

*# optionally check to see if anything is owned by root:*

```
ls -la ~/.npm
```

*# take ownership of everything in your ~/.npm directory (must be run with sudo):*

```
sudo chown -R $USER:`id -g -n $USER` ~/.npm
```

*Reinstall your global packages
Finally, reinstall all your global packages (the ones you checked for in the first step)… this time without sudo!*

*# no sudo necessary :)*

```
npm install -g bower
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install -g gulp
npm install -g yo
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте пояснение: что именно произойдет в результате выполнения данной команды; и каким образом это решит проблему, указанную в вопросе.